# Running supertuxkart in a separate X server doesn't work as expected

Tags: x11, x-server

I tried to run supertuxkart in a separate X server (to be able to access my desktop)

I ran

```
xinit supertuxkart -- :1
```

The game launches, but there's no cursor. What am I doing wrong?
Running `libx11-6` version `2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2` and Nvidia proprietary drivers, version `331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4`

Comment: I think you still need a window manager running behind it.

Comment: So is there any way to run it in a separate X server? I'd like to be able to access the apps behind it.